# Private WiFi network between OSX and Android

Tags: network, wifi, remote-control, android, tethering

I want to use a remote control app for presentations I'm giving offsite, using my Android phone as a remote for my MacBook. (the software is [Unified Remote](https://www.unifiedremote.com/))

I have no guarantee that I can access a WiFi network offsite (or that there will even be one), so I wanted to keep things simple and just setup a private AdHoc network.

To my dismay, I have discovered that Androids do not recognise the AdHoc network created by MacBooks.

What other viable solutions are there?

I have to give presentations often, so I'm hoping for a solution that is easily switchable between normal WiFi use and "presentation mode".

Other options I've looked into
Using the connection sharing under Sharing -> Internet, but as I have no other active connection, this is disabled.

I've tried the solutions listed in [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5100928/how-to-connect-android-wifi-to-adhoc-wifi) but they seem to be windows only.

Answer (score 1):

Other than your self-found answer, my suggestion would have been to get an [Airport Express](http://store.apple.com/us/product/MC414LL/A/airport-express) base station and take it with you all the time.  All it is requiring is an extra power outlet.

Any other router would possibly do as well, but the Airport Express is fairly small and fits into almost every pocket.

Since you frequently do presentations and it can be used at home or elsewhere as well, the price tag would not be too bad either.

Answer (score 0):

Seems I was wrong about Apples Internet connection sharing, you can in fact share an inactive connection (eg internet), and create a Hotspot that Android can see in that way.

An example is at this site: https://gigaom.com/2008/05/22/create-a-wifi-hotspot-share-your-internet-connection-in-leopard/